# Android display an image based on a calculation

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText box where the user inputs a number and 3 TextViews that display the result of some calculations. Instead of showing "2" as the result, I would like to show a specific picture based on the result. i.e. "1"=pic1 "2"=pic2....

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you really want to do? Could you give a complete explanation for the cases you want to cover?

Comment: I have an EditText box where the user inputs a number and 3 TextViews that display the result of some calculations.  Instead of showing "2" as the result, I would like to show a specific picture based on the result. i.e. "1"=pic1 "2"=pic2....

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load a picture from the /sdcard based on the result of the calculations, then this is one way of doing it:


`int calculationsResult = ... //do your calculations here

String fileName = "/sdcard/path_to_your_pictures/pic" + calculationsResult + ".jpg";
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);

ImageView resultImageHolder = findViewById(R.id.result_holder_id);

resultimageHolder.setImageBitmap(image);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all results are integers, you could do it like Todor suggests (by giving each picture a predictable title that you can use). Another way of getting the right filename, though, would be to simply use a HashMap to describe what image should be shown for what result.

```
Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

// Put elements to the map 
hm.put(new Integer(2), "number_two.png");
hm.put(new Integer(20), "the_number_is_twenty.png");
hm.put(new Integer(42), "douglas_adams.png"); 

And when you have done your calculation, you look up in the HashMap to find the filename.
Integer result = 3+1-2; // Your calculation here

String filename = "dummy.png"; // When all else fails
if (hm.containsKey(result))
{
        filename=(String)hm.get(result);
}
```